# Worksheet_Calculate Repeating

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and my script keeps repeating, I'm unsure as to why. Is anyone able to help me with this? 
I just want to run the script 'mail_small_text_outlook' when any of the values J3:K4 are calculated to be greater than 10. J3:K4 are recalculated automatically every 30 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Dim target As Range
  Set target = Range("J3:K4")
  If target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If IsNumeric(target) And target > 10 Then
    Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It will repeat every time the worksheet is calculated.  Does `Mail_smal_Text_Outlook` change any values on the sheet?  Try putting `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of the procedure and change it back to `True` at the end.

Comment: `target` is more than a single cell so by itself you can't test if it's >10 and you shouldn't be able to check if it's `IsNumeric` - are you getting `type mismatch` errors?  You could check if the sum is > 10 or if any individual cells are > 10 (as @Kostarsus answered)

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over the cells in the range

```
  Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("J3:K4")
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In target.Cells
        If IsNumeric(cell) And cell > 10 Then
            Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
        End If
    Next cel
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but now it doesn't recall the script automatically when the sheet updates.

Comment: The Worksheet_Calculate is an event, which is called, after the update of a sheet [https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)). Did you debugged the event? What happens exactly, when the event is called? How was called the  automatically recalculation every 30 min?

Comment: I've set the worksheet to update the imported data from a .csv file every minute. When the data is updated I have a very basic calculation of the data: 
Get the median and the calculate the difference between each of the median values. My script works perfectly when I run it manually, it just doesn't work when the sheet updates automatically and then recalculates. Should I input something into the script that tells it to run every half hour or something?